# Mocking a resource from outerscope of a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function that uses a dictionary, constructed out of the function, and do something. The function is like this:

```
TRANSLATION_TABLE = {#something}

def get_translate(tokens_and_tags):
results = []
for token, tag in tokens_and_tags:
    results.append((TRANSLATION_TABLE.get(token, token), tag))
return results
```

Now I want to write test for it, but, I could not find how to mock the "TRANSLATION_TABLE" dictionary properly.

What is the correct way to test this function and mocking the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use dependency injection

```
def get_translate(tokens_and_tags, translation_table=None)
  translation_table = translation_table or TRANSLATION_TABLE
```

Now you can inject a fake in your test.

```
def test_get_translate(...):
  ...
  expect = ...
  actual = get_translate(fake_tokens_and_tags, {...})
  assert actual == expect.
```